# Xamarin Android error XA0136 deployment errors

Tags: c#, xamarin, compiler-errors, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to deploy my Xamarin.Android application from visual studio to my smartphone which is Huawei P10. During compilation a popup shows up:

[image]

After you close the popup an error shows up:

[image]

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error       XA0136: The 'run-as' command failed with 'run-as: package has corrupt installation: com.companyname.app1'.
The currently installation of the package in corrupt. Please manually uninstall the
package from all the users on device and try again. If that does not work you can disable Fast Deployment.
Fast Deployment can be disabled in the Visual Studio project property pages or edit the project file in a text editor and set the 'EmbedAssembliesIntoApk' MSBuild property to 'true'.

**Tools and Devices used:**

1. Visual Studio 2019 version 16.10.1
2. Xamarin Android
3. Deploy to Huawei P10 Android 9.0 API 28

Any suggestions pls on what is the problem.

Thanks

**UPDATE**: If you disable Fast Deployment works fine

Comment: there are two fairly explicit suggestions in the error message.  Have you tried either of them?

Comment: @Jason I tried the first suggestion the second suggestion not yet because this application was working.

Answer (score 2):

According to Xamarin, you have to activate the developer mode for this. In addition, debugging via USB must be approved. You can find the exact statement [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/guides/messages/xa0131.md) on GitHub. If you don't know how to activate the mode, you can find instructions [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-run-xamarin-android-app-in-android-phone-using-visual-studio-2015-update/).

Alternatively, if all these steps did not work you can disable 'Fast development'. Either do [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-process#fast-deployment) in your project or via Visual Studio.

[image]

Fast deployment is known to fail on devices which block run-as, which often includes devices older than Android 5.0. Fast deployment also fails for system applications (android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system") since run-as is also blocked for system applications.

If these solutions work let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue when trying to run the app in emulator. But I fixed it by changing to new android emulator